# Is a function or not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functions, foundations

A space $X=\{1,2\}$ and the topology $\tau=\{\phi,X,\{1\}\}$;  $Y=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology $\Im_{u}.$ Thus, the function $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\Im_u)$ is defined,
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
  \mathbb{Q}\quad \  x=2 \\
  \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q} \quad  \ x=1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Is this a function, i used it as a function, but they told me its not a function.
Can you tell me why it's not a function.

Comment: It's not a function $f:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (Y,\Im_u)$, because $\mathbb{Q} \notin \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A function needs to return an element of the range, not a subset of the range.

Comment: Aha, i got it. Thanks for you two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $f$ is a function from $\{1,2\}$ into $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$, the power set of the real line, so $f:\{1,2\}\to\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$. It is NOT a function $f:\{1,2\}\to\Bbb{R}$, because the outputs of your $f$ are sets of real numbers, not real numbers themselves.

Comment: Ok, thanks. know, i can understand it.